# How do I track multiple databases in schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

schema.rb traditionally holds the schema for the default :development, :test and :production schemas. My problem is that my application relies on two other databases other than those defaults. How do I track these other databases in schema.rb so that when I launch the app on a new server rake db:schema:load really creates all the needed databases?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord is not designed for multiple connections. You can hack to work with the [magic multi connection gem.](http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_multi_connections/) This allows you specify different connections by calling `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` in a declared module `module`.